# AWS Redundancy for a Single Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, load-balancing, redundancy

Small stateful app on AWS.  Statefullness is the issue and for sake of argument assume that the app must remain stateful.  How can we create redundancy across multiple AZs?

Half Baked Ideas:
1)  Mirrored setup in AZ1 and AZ2.  Use ELB to route all traffic to AZ1.  If there are health problems, stop routing to AZ1 and route to AZ2. Is this even possible?  Isn't that like anti-load-balancing?

2)  Use lambda to "Turn On" and instance already created in AZ2 when AZ1 has health issues.  Would also turn off instance in AZ1.  If so, could you point me towards some lambda documents?

3)  Something way better and probably easier than 1 or 2

p.s.  I know how to easily accomplish if the app was not stateful.  Unfortunately the statefullness cannot be adjusted.

Comment: You don't give enough information to properly answer your question. What exactly do you mean by "stateful"? Do you mean persistent HTTP sessions? Do you mean some sort of state files stored on the server?  In general you just need to store your "state" in a central location like ElastiCache, a database, etc. If you provide specifics about your environment we could provide a specific answer.

Comment: Put an instance in each zone and use an [ELB with sticky sessions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html). Done.

Comment: Agreed with Mark B, but to answer your question about adding instances when you experience health issues, you should deploy your EC2 instance into an Auto Scale Group, which will monitor the health of the instance(s) and deploy additional instances when it notices unhealthy ones.  Between the ELB and Auto Scale Group health monitoring, you're covered.  No need to try to manipulate the ELB routing (this is done behind the scenes already) or involve Lambda.  As Ben Whaley said, if you just need statefulness within each session, turn on sticky sessions in the load balancer.

Comment: Not my design.  State = cookie based sessions, in this q

Answer (score 0):

By statefullness I am assuming you need a central store for data.

**Choosing technology to store state data:**

1) If the nature of state retrieval is not chatty or the performance requirements are not extreme, i.e. not more than once to and fro's from the server to retrieve state you should choose DynamoDb to store the state, this is multi-az by default you dont have to do anything to make it HA.

2) In a high performance scenario or when multiple round trips are needed to retrieve state (try to avoid this) you can choose memcached which is available as an option in AWS elastiCache where you can deploy them in multiple AZ's for HA.

**For HA of front end servers:**

1) Just add servers into multiple AZ's and attach them to the load balancer, in order to do this:

a) Add two subnets using the VPC service into more than one AZ.

b) Create a load balancer and give it both of these subnets (this makes your LB HA), make sure to enable "Cross-Zone Load Balancing", this will distribute traffic evenly to the servers attached to it across zones.

c) Create two (minimum) app servers and add one to each subnet in different AZ, add both of them to the above created LB.

2) Make sure that your servers retrieve and store state from a central data layer (which is also HA now).

You are good to go, you can optionally setup auto scaling in AWS using launch configs and auto scaling groups if that's a requirement which I'm guessing it will be.